# usage: supply url to fetch JSOUP error

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

```
public void singleParser(String url)
{
    try {
        Document doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element body=doc.body();
        System.out.println(body.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SingleFileParser parser = new SingleFileParser();
    parser.singleParser("http://www.xxxx.com/xxx.html");
}
```

I am getting this weird error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: supply url to fetch
at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
at org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main(HtmlToPlainText.java:26)
```

can anybody help? Why am I getting this error 
**usage: supply url to fetch**
 I am using jsoup-1.7.3.jar for the above piece of code.

Comment: Code compiles and runs just fine for me locally even with that strange looking url. Not sure what your issue is.

Comment: Are you running this from the IDE?  Is this all of the code?

Comment: I was running this from eclipse.

Comment: I switched the workspace and it works fine now. Weird!!!

Comment: If your problem is solved, please post your solution as an answer and *accept* it. Thanks.

Comment: As this seems to have been a local IDE error, I've flagged this as unreproducible.